# Laravel 5.4 function index try using function show

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have route:

```
Route::resource('admin/question', 'QuestionsController');
```

and function `index`:

```
public function index() {

  return "Hello";

}
```

But when I try used index Laravel returned me the error:

> Method [show] does not exist.

I'm using the link:

```
http://localhost:8012/siwz/siwz/public/admin/question
```

The server is WampServer program.
I can only use index function when I change route file:

```
Route::get('admin/question/index', 'QuestionsController@index');
Route::resource('admin/question', 'QuestionsController');
```

In Laravel version 5.3 I did not have to do it, it was enough to use:

```
Route::resource('.../...', '...Controller');
```

Comment: Just try to add the function name in route : `Route::resource('admin/question', 'QuestionsController@index');`

Comment: @VincentDecaux it is incorrect to specify a method name when registering a resourceful route. What you can do though is this `Route::resource('question', 'QuestionController', ['only' => ['index']]);`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the URL is going to the correct function. `admin/question` should go to `index`. `admin/question/{question}` is the route that goes to `show`.

Take a look here and check how Laravel create Resource routes:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Since that you didn't provide your full routes. I am guessing that the link you were accessing is going to the wrong controller. You should check the ordering of the routes. Maybe you are accessing something like this on your route,

```
Route::resource('admin','AdminController');
```

And the AdminController doesn't have a method show(). Thats why laravel return that error.

Here's you can do

- Comment out the rest of routes except route that you are accessing.
- Try to reorder the affected routes. Maybe Laravel is confused with your route.